# List of tuples to just list using map haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to convert list of tuples: [(2,2,2), (3,3,3), (4,4,4), (5,5,5)] to just list:
[2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]

I try this

```
map (\(a,b,c,d)->a:b:c:d) listOfTuples
```

but get an error.

```
Prelude> map (\(a,b,c)->a:b:c) [(1,2,3), (5,6,7)]

<interactive>:1:37:
    No instance for (Num [t])
      arising from the literal `7' at <interactive>:1:37
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [t])
    In the expression: 7
    In the expression: (5, 6, 7)
    In the second argument of `map', namely `[(1, 2, 3), (5, 6, 7)]'

Prelude>
```

How can I do it with lambda? And why my stuff does not work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`a:b:c:d` is invalid because it's `a : (b : (c : d))`. `(:)` takes a list on the right-hand side and an element to prepend to it on the left-hand side, but `d` is another element, not (necessarily) a list. You probably mean `a:b:c:d:[]`, which is the same as `[a,b,c,d]`.

If you make that change, the code will run, and produce `[[2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4], [5,5,5]]`, since `map` applies the function to each element of the list, and uses its result as the new element; that is, cannot change the *structure* of the list, only each element independently. If you want it flattened, you'll need to use `concat` (which has the type `[[a]] -> [a]`, and flattens a list of lists):

```
concat (map (\(a,b,c,d) -> [a,b,c,d]) listOfTuples)
```

However, there is a ready-made composition of `concat` and `map`, which is more idiomatic to use:

```
concatMap (\(a,b,c,d) -> [a,b,c,d]) listOfTuples
```

Comment: But can I do it with just map? I'm interested in algorithmic difficulty of concatMap.

Comment: @overwriter: No, you cannot do it with just `map`, since each element of the input list maps to exactly one element in the output list.

Comment: hammar is right; I've updated my answer to hopefully make that more clear.

Comment: Or: `foldr (\(a,b,c) l -> a:b:c:l) [] [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]`

Comment: @overwriter: The answer Riccardo gives is just what you want, since you seem to only want to traverse the list once.

Comment: @amindfv: Thanks to laziness, `concatMap f xs` will only traverse the list once; the same applies to `concat (map f xs)`.

Comment: Because of how the list monad is implemented, this opens up for: `[(a,b,c),(d,e,f)] >>= \(x,y,z) -> [x,y,z]`

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done more succinctly with a list comprehension.

Assuming:

```
let listOfTuples = [(2,2,2), (3,3,3), (4,4,4), (5,5,5)]
```

then this list comprehension:

```
concat [[a,b,c] | (a, b, c) <- listOfTuples]
```

produces:

```
[2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]
```